# Is there any way to get predicted variables using python script?

Tags: ghidra

I have a simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a;
  a = func(15, 3);
  return a;
}

int func(int i, int j)
{
  int b1[5], b2[10];

  b2[i] = 1;
  printf("%d\n", b1[j]);

  return 0;
}
```

I am using python script to get local variables from the stripped binary, compiled using above program.

I use: `function.getLocalVariables()` or something like `function.getStackFrame().getStackVariables()` to get the local variables. Interestingly I observed that, this script doesn't give me all the variables which can be seen in the decompiler window. For e.g., in the above case, I get following in the decompiled window (for function `func`):

[image]

Here, the predicted buffers can be seen. But instead I get:

```
FUN_004004d6
array(ghidra.program.model.listing.Variable, [[undefined4 local_5c@Stack[-0x5c]:4], [undefined4 local_60@Stack[-0x60]:4]])
```

which are clearly not the predicted buffers. Is there any way to get those buffers?

Note: I also posted the same on ghidra github's forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone wondering, I posted this question on ghidra github as well and @cetfor posted a very good way to do this. You can find that question [here](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/2143).

I tried to reproduce it and I was able to do this successfully.

> ```
> from ghidra.app.decompiler import DecompileOptions
> from ghidra.app.decompiler import DecompInterface
>
> ifc = DecompInterface()
> ifc.setOptions(DecompileOptions())
> ifc.openProgram(currentProgram)
>
> for function in functions:
>     res = ifc.decompileFunction(function, 60, monitor)
>     high_func = res.getHighFunction()
>     lsm = high_func.getLocalSymbolMap()
>     symbols = lsm.getSymbols()
>
>     for i, symbol in enumerate(symbols):
>       print("Symbol {}: {} (size: {})".format(i+1, symbol.getName(), symbol.size))
> ```

Check out [this](https://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/ghidra/program/model/pcode/HighFunction.html) endpoint for more information on highfunction. Note that I found differences in variables given by this decompiler interface and listing. Also, I couldn't find any api endpoint which gives address references by these variables (something like `getReferencesTo`).

Comment: I am still not getting the meaning of getHighFunction(). What is the use of this basically?